# Merge two strings while removing duplicated values with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, merge

I have two strings that I want to merge:

```
str_1 = "A5 Coupé (B8)"
str_2 = "A5 Coupé 2,0 T FSI"
```

This could of course be done by calling

```
str_1 + str_2
```

But I want to have a string that contains 'A5 Coupe' only once:

```
"A5 Coupé 2,0 T FSI (B8)"
```

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `|` operator to grab the union of the individual words present in both Strings:

```
str_1 = "A5 Coupé (B8)"
str_2 = "A5 Coupé 2,0 T FSI"

puts ( str_2.split | str_1.split ).join(' ')
# => "A5 Coupé 2,0 T FSI (B8)"
```

For an arbitrary number of Strings you can do it like this:

```
strings = [
  "A5 Coupé (B8)",
  "A5 Coupé 2,0 T FSI",
  "A5 Coupé 2,0 Special Edition",
  "A5 Coupé 2,0 Mini",
  "A5 Coupé (B8)",
  "A5 Coupé"
]

puts strings.reduce([]) { |words, str| words | str.split }.join(' ')
# => "A5 Coupé (B8) 2,0 T FSI Special Edition Mini"
```

The `.reduce` function iterates the Array, building up a result value which starts as the empty Array `[]`. For every String `str` in `strings`, it will replace the currently built up value (which is an Array of words) by the union of the current value and the individual words of each `str` (so basically, adding words to the Array which were not present yet).

Answer (score 1):

You can split the strings apart using the space as a separator, then join together the unique results. In order to satisfy your example, `str_2` needs to come first.

```
[str_2, str_1].map {|str| str.split(' ') }.flatten.uniq.join(' ')
```

Comment: Yields `undefined method `split' for ["A5 Coup\u00E9 2,0 T FSI", "A5 Coup\u00E9 (B8)"]:Array `. You probably want to map the split function over each string.

Comment: Sorry, it's too early in the morning. Forgot the `map` block.